# React-select initial value not being set when retrieved from postgres table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, react-select

I am using react-select and I am trying to set my `value` prop to pre-existing value for that record.

I am retrieving the data from a postgres db and it is be returned as follows:

`"{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}"`

What I am then attempting to do is push this to an array as follows:

```
let data = "{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}"
let selectValues = []
selectValues.push(data)
console.log(selectValues)
```

The console log for `selectValues` array returns the following result when expanding the array in dev tool's console:

```
0: "{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}"
```

When I then attempt to assign this array to my react-select component `value` below, the initial values are not being displayed.

The thing is though, if I hardcode the array object as shown against the commented out line, for value, it works.

Not sure what I am missing with my approach above with pushing the string object to my `selectValues` array.

```
<Select 
  name="my-select"
  styles={customStyles}
  options={options}
  isMulti={true}
  value={selectValues}
  // value={[{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}]}
  placeholder={'Options....'}
/>
```

Comment: @Kris - oh. Could you pls suggest a way of not pushing the string/removing the double quotes prior to pushing to `selectValues` array?

Comment: where this `selectValues.push` is happening?  probably your component rendered before push happened, then as Kris mentioned `data` is not an array of two objects, it is a string

Comment: `let selectValues = [{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}]`  and there is no `push` needed

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving a string from the DB?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi - tried your approach but the array still contains a string from console log `0: "{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}"`. Unsure how to remove double-quotes?

Comment: @Kris - looks to be - yes

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(response)? 'response' is what you receive from the DB.

Comment: @Kris - I was going to try this but doesn't react-select expect the values in this format: `{value:2,label:'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}` and not `{"value":2,"label":'Dog'},{value:4,label:'Cat'}` ?

Comment: The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. I have the feelings that you are receiving a JSON from the DB, so you have to parse it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237693/discussion-between-kris-and-arthurj).

Comment: @Kris - fyi, I left a comment in the discussion chat

Comment: @Kris - could you pls add your comment re: `JSON.parse()` as a solution, so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a `JSON` string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. I have the feelings that you are receiving a JSON from the DB, so you have to parse it.

For more information read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)